# Ng2 throws DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeLoadedTemplate error

Tags: angular

Suddenly my angular 2 application throws an *DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeLoadedTemplate* error.

[image]

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same problem but it wasn't necessarily a self closing tag.

To figure out the exact location of the error. I used the chrome debugger and enabled the "Pause On Uncaught Exception".
When it stops on `throw new Error("Template parse errors:\n" + errorString);` the errorString has the exact info.

Don't know why chrome doesn't show the complete message.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found it !!
*instead of writing :*

```
<avatar [name]="name" />
```

**you need to use:**

```
<avatar [name]="name"></avatar>
```

Explanation: 
When writing your own components, and using them declaratively, you cannot use the self closing tag = '/>'.
You always need to use begin- & end-tags.